# Rest APIs in Python - Get Authentication token and then set it as a variable to use for POST

Tags: python, api, rest, authentication, token

I am pretty new to Python (please bear with me) and I am trying to make a POST request to upload a file to a certain SQL server. One thing is really confusing me.

Before I make my POST request to upload my file I need to get an authorization token via a different POST request. Instead of copy and pasting the authorization token into my file upload script, I want to just have one script that gets the authentication token and uses it by itself... set the authorization token I get as a variable from the first POST request and then use it again for the file upload POST request automatically.

FIRST POST Request for authorization:

```
url = '...url'
payload = '...username&password'
headers = '...headers'
response = '"POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload'
#response has extra characters, removing the characters and adding apostrophes to get the authentication token. 
#Also taking out any backslashes, which appear in the response along with front slashes but are not needed
authenticationtoken = "'" + response.text.replace('{"ticket":"', ').replace('"}', '').replace('\\', '') + "'"
```

If I ask to print the variable "authenticationtoken" and copy and paste the response into the next part, everything works perfectly. If I copy and paste this response and set it as a different variable in the second part (something like a = 'myauthenticationtokenabc/123' and then use the variable "a" where I need my authentication token), it works perfectly. But if I try to use the variable "authenticationtoken" in the second part, I get an authentication error. What gives?

SECOND POST Request for file upload (does not work with authenticationtoken variable:)

```
files = {'file': open(r"...path", "rb")}
data = { 'type':...type, 'parent_id': ...parentid, 'name': 'DummyFile' }
url = "...url"
headers = {'ticket': authenticationtoken }
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, data=data)
print cs.text
```

Hopefully I copied everything into this post correctly. Everything works fine but only if I am copy and pasting the result of print(authenticationtoken) from the first part and copy and pasting the result to the second part. I am always getting an "authentication error" if I try using the variable (even though the script has no problem at using a variable, since I can copy and paste the result and set it as a different variable and it works). Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. When defining "authenticationissue" I was adding two apostrophes but these were not needed. Thanks :)